# how to store multiple values under same key using hashing in c++

Tags: c++, hash

i want to make a telephone directory project in c++ using hashing technique.One thing i need to do is it must search for contacts based on the location.so i will make the location as key value but there will be multiple contacts in same location.so how to store multiple values(name,phone number) under same key(location).

Comment: Use `std::unordered_multimap`.

Comment: @DannyuNDos is that a part of hashing technique?

Comment: This is a hash table that is able to store multiple elements with same key.

Comment: thanks i will check it out....

Comment: "but there will be multiple contacts in same location.so how to store multiple values(name,phone number) under same key(location)." - You are speaking about two different things here. Do you want multiple values due to multiple entries or due to different properties (name, phone number, ...) of one entry?

Comment: @JojOatXGME i didn't actually get you..i just want to store multiple contact info i.e values under same location

Comment: @sujanthapa I think that the sentence I cited is ambiguous because you are referring to "name" and "phone number" as "multiple values". But I think they are "one value" together in your context.

Comment: no name and phone numbers are two different inputs taken from users but stored under a same key value in a hash table @JojOatXGME

Comment: here the main point is not the name or number. the main focus is that a particular location(say uk) can have multiple contacts.ex. a man can have multiple relatives staying in a common location.So during search operation i have to take location as the input from user and display all the records under that(user input) location @BoPersson

Comment: i have tried to store the location in an array index and then link the array index to a linked list but i'm stuck and still trying and someone suggested me to use unordered map and i'm just getting information about it from google.@DieterMeemken

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *C++11* or newer, you could use `std::unordered_multimap` to store multiple entries per key (e.g. multiple entries per location). It is a hash map that allows multiple entries with the same key. To store multiple properties per entry, you can use a struct or class. Finally, it could look like this:

```
struct contact_t {
    std::string name;
    std::string phone_number;
}

std::unordered_multimap<std::string, contact_t> directory;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Add entry
    contact_t contact;
    contact.name = "Fooman";
    contact.phone_number = "00 000 00000000";
    directory.emplace("Barcity", contact);

    // List all entries of one city
    auto range = directory.equal_range("Barcity");
    for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
        auto &entry = it->second; // it->first would be the key/location
        std::cout << "Name: " << entry.name
                  << "Phone: " << entry.phone_number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, consider that values with the same key are not sorted. You may want to use something like `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::multiset<contact_t>>` instead.